# doctrine2 paginator error for group by

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I use this DQL to get some data but i get an error when using doctrine2 paginator:

```
SELECT f FROM DankeForumBundle:Forumusermessage f
  WHERE f.recipientdelete=0
  GROUP BY f.forwarder
  HAVING f.recipient=:recipient
```

This is because doctrine executes this query to count pages:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT f.id) FROM Forumusermessage AS f
  WHERE f.recipientdelete=0
  GROUP BY f.forwarder_id
  HAVING f.recipient_id=:recipient
```

Is there any way to paginate this without using native SQL queries?

EDIT:

This is an example PHP code:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT f FROM DankeForumBundle:Forumusermessage f
  WHERE f.recipientdelete=0
  GROUP BY f.forwarder
  HAVING f.recipient=:recipient');
$query->setParameter('recipient', $user);
$query->setFirstResult(0);
$query->setMaxResults(10);
$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);
echo count($paginator); // wrong page count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an workaround using subqueries:

```
SELECT f FROM DankeForumBundle:Forumusermessage f
WHERE
  f.recipientdelete=0 AND
  f.recipient=:recipient
  AND f.id IN (
    SELECT fn FROM DankeForumBundle:Forumusermessage fn
    GROUP BY fn.forwarder
  )
```